# passing NULL to .id in ldply returns error

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to use `ldply` without creating an .id column. In the `plyr::ldply` documentation it says,

> .id    Pass NULL to avoid creation of the index column.

but when I try this,

```
require(plyr)
foo <- list(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
ldply(foo, .id=NULL, FUN=mean)
```

I get,

> Error in if (is.na(.id)) { : argument is of length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In is.na(.id) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just don't enter anything, like `ldply(foo,FUN=mean)`. Maybe the documentation has a mistake.

Comment: I am not getting an error with the code using `plyr_1.8.2`

Comment: @akrun you're right, updating solves it. Thank you.